# How do I approach a coworker about his or her code quality?

Tags: code-quality, communication

I work on a new venture at a large enterprise software company (3000+ programmers). In my group, we have a bunch of projects and people usually work on several projects over the course of a year.

I just started work on a project that has been previously maintained by a buddy of mine (consultant who's been with us for 3+ years) to add some features. I got into the code, and the quality was really quite poor. Whether it was on the UI frontend or the services backend, the code simply wasn't indented, there were hundreds of lines commented out for no apparent reason, documentation was basically non-existent, coding standards weren't applied consistently (e.g. mixing `camelCase` and `under_scored_variables`), variable names were unintelligible, datatype choices were wrong, etc. etc.

I'm very much a non-confrontational person, so I don't want to attack my coworker, but I also don't just wanto to go to my boss and complain about his performance. What are the kinds of things I could say to politely mention that the code is poorly structured?

**EDIT:**

I want to clarify that while I understand there is an element of "Everyone else's code sucks" to all programmers, when I see something like this (names are chosen on purpose and some details left out/changed in this example):

```
public void doCalculate(Object argument) {
  if (argument instanceof String) {
    String argument2 = (String) argument;
    if (argument2 == "DataBase") {
      // do something
    } else {
      long argument3;
      try {
        argument3 = Long.parseLong(argument2);
      } catch (Exception e) {
        argument3 = -1;
      }
      // do something completely unrelated
    }
  }
}
```

I think it's objectively fair to say that this is **not** a good idea. Furthermore, I'm not dealing with a newbie here (I'm only coding 3 years now). He's got maybe 20 years of experience on me. The advice you guys have given so far is great; just wanna make sure that we're not talking about a "fine line" here.

Comment: I don't think this is a duplicate: speaking to your boss and speaking to your coworker is entirely different.

Comment: I feel it shouldn't matter if the other person is a co-worker or a boss, they're still both people and you should approach them the same way and with the same amount of respect.

Comment: @Rachel: I think it depends on the boss. If they aren't very approachable and don't take kindly to criticism, there could be consequences.

Comment: None of the defects you mentioned were especially egregious. Sounds like ordinary lackluster production code to me. They may be symptoms of deeper problems but those things aren't particularly horrifying by themselves. If you have a problem that is keeping you from making progress, then it is worth asking the original dev for help. Otherwise, not worth the hassle to get on someone's case about indentation and variable names and some inconsistencies.

Comment: Buy/loan him the book Clean Code, and tell him it really helped you, and you think he would enjoy it. And...read the book yourself if you haven't! It really is quite good.

Comment: Are code reviews usual at your place? If not, you might want to suggest them. That's the time for the reviewers to point out these bad practices.

Comment: Did he originate *all* of this code? If not, there's the possibility that he was dealing with some legacy code and was just trying to get it working. The mix of camelCase and underscore names sort of points in that direction. I've really had to bite my tongue (fingers?) a couple of times when dealing with seriously crufty legacy stuff. Sometimes I've even put in a comment saying, "It's not my fault!"

Comment: Right now, my manager's skype status is "done is better than perfect"...

Comment: Also be very careful with your underlying assumption that his code is worse than yours would be.  You might learn a thing or two.

Comment: Don't you have other work to do, like writing your own code ?

Comment: @Jas fair criticism, except that I'm inheriting his codebase.

Comment: @PeterRowell yes, he wrote it from scratch.

Comment: @PeteWilson No they are not usual practice, which is part of the problem.

Comment: @daveslab - if you're inheriting his codebase (I suppose he's moving on to something else), what's the point actually in talking to him about the code quality ? In your place, I'd simply isolate his codebase via a set of interfaces and continue to write my own code as I see fit. Or if you have to maintain that same codebase, I'd gradually introduce change. At my current workplace, I managed to replace a 500-line long Java progie with an awk one-liner. Mentioned it to the previous owner? No, would have made no difference. Mentioned it to my manager? Hell,yeah.

Comment: That's pretty ugly...he probably hacked that together without any thought...or evil thoughts. If you get the chance to refactor I think even a newb could come up with a cleaner function than that.

Comment: the code example above is perfectly valid java code. That's the kind of code experienced programmers write -- every line is clearly designed to be there.... whether you disagree with the chosen primitives is different matter completely...

Answer (score 45):

Ask him to explain his code to you

Tell him you've never seen X programmed that way before, and ask him why he codes it that way. Show him the way you code it, and tell why you do it that way (best practices, better performance, less chance of errors, easier for other programmers to read/maintain, etc).

Be sure to prepare all your arguments in advance, and focus on why your method is best instead of why his method is worst. Afterwards, see if he still supports his method over yours.

If he is open to improvement, he will likely change his way of coding. If he still prefers to use his style of coding over yours, you are not likely to change his opinion.

---

This is the exact same answer I gave for the question [How to tell your boss that his programming style is really bad?](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/q/45856/1130). I originally voted to close this question as a duplicate, however enough people thought it was different enough to warrent re-opening it. My answer is still the same though, regardless of if you're talking to a boss or a co-worker.

Comment: +1 I was going to write a similar answer before I saw this one come up.  I'd also add that unless he has a lot of spare time or is instructed to do so, I doubt he'll fix his old code -- but it might convince him to do better in the future.  I'd also wonder whether it was such a mess before *he* worked on it (if he wasn't the first)...

Comment: this seems pretty formal for talking to a coworker

Comment: @Ryathal It doesn't have to be format at all. For example, you could ask them what their naming convention is, or why they have two different ones. Then follow up with your own naming convention and why you use it. You could also ask them what the large commented out code does and if it's OK to remove it, and then explain that the old code will be in version control if they every want to access it. How you phrase the questions will likely be related to how comfortable you are with the person.

Comment: I might also add to ask him about code he wrote a month+ ago.  Even an author wont be able to grok his own code with bad variable names, bad indentation, etc.

Comment: You wouldn't believe the number of people who just code without thinking about WHY. "Why" stumps their own selves, and they don't bother to ask why others code in whatever way. Just follow like a rigid template and we're full of win! Next project!

Answer (score 14):

What if instead of approaching him personally, you approach the team and in a completely neutral way propose on "team" coming up with a coding standard/guidelines as a way for different team members to work more efficiently with each other's code.

Once that is in place, I think the code you have concerns with will bubble up to the top all on its own.

Peer code reviews also help in this area. Coding standards don't have much benefit if no one ever looks at the code.  But peer code reviews have many other benefits, primary one knowledge transfer, so you should push to introduce them in either case.

I'm making an assumption that even if you have 3000+ engineers, you guys have MUCH smaller sub teams that work together as a unit

Answer (score 12):

Your co-worker is probably not the root cause of the problem in your company. The reason that poor quality code gets into production is the lack of automatically measurable coding standards in your company. In this case, sunlight is the best medicine.

You should talk to your technical lead about implementing automated source code quality metrics in your group. The system should run at least weekly, e-mail everyone on the team a file-by-file list of coding standard violations, and send an executive summary to your boss. The summary should contain the number of violations per project.

In my experience, anything that gets measured and reported to a boss improves over time.

Comment: Real code quality is not measurable.

Comment: IMHO, this is the best answer.

Answer (score 12):

> **...the code simply wasn't indented, there were hundreds of lines commented out for no apparent reason, documentation was basically non-existent, coding standards weren't applied consistently (e.g. mixing camelCase and under_scored_variables), variable names were unintelligible, datatype choices were wrong...**

As far as I can tell, above matches #12, #9, #5, #2 and probably #7 of [Top 12 things likely to be overheard if you had a Klingon Programmer (archive)](https://web.archive.org/web/20111017235800/http://monster-island.org/tinashumor/humor/klingonprog.html) <del>[[original link](http://monster-island.org/tinashumor/humor/klingonprog.html)]</del>:

> 12. Specifications are for the weak and timid!
>   11. This machine is a piece of GAGH! I need dual Pentium processors if I am to do battle with this code!
>   10. You cannot really appreciate Dilbert unless you've read it in the original Klingon.
>   9. Indentation?! - I will show you how to indent when I indent your skull!
>   8. What is this talk of 'release'? Klingons do not make software 'releases.' Our software 'escapes,' leaving a bloody trail of designers and quality assurance people in its wake.
>   7. Klingon function calls do not have 'parameters' - they have 'arguments' - and they ALWAYS WIN THEM.
>   6. Debugging? Klingons do not debug. Our software does not coddle the weak.
>   5. I have challenged the entire quality assurance team to a Bat-Leth contest. They will not concern us again.
>   4. A TRUE Klingon Warrior does not comment his code!
>   3. By filing this PTR you have challenged the honor of my family. Prepare to die!
>   2. You question the worthiness of my code? I should kill you where you stand!
>   1. Our users will know fear and cower before our software! Ship it! Ship it and let them flee like the dogs they are!

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/16MVS.png]

It is quite likely that the only way to avoid confrontation is a [warp drive](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Warp_drive_%28Star_Trek%29) into another space quadrant.

Comment: The link in "_Top 12 things likely to be overheard if you had a Klingon Programmer_" is not working. Could you fix it?

Comment: @user31782 nope, the page is available only in WayBack machine. There's always a [risk for link to go away](http://meta.stackexchange.com/tags/link-only-answers/info "that's why link-only answers are frowned upon"), that's why **I took care of quoting essential content here from the very start**

Comment: ...upon further thinking, it might be convenient for readers to know that original link has gone. Not sure if it's important enough to justify answer edit, but I upvoted your comment to help them see

Answer (score 11):

First, everybody thinks other people's code sucks.

Second, maybe he inherited the code from someone/someplace else OR this was a prototype never intended to be the code used for the actual project but of course that's what ended up being used.

Third, maybe his code really does suck but is it your job to badmouth previous developers? Unless you have built up a reputation that commands respect around the company I suspect if you do whine about the other person's code it is you that will end up looking bad and not your friend. The time for giving people grief about their code is when code reviews are held. At least then it is part of your job responsibilities.

I recommend that if you don't like his code then fix it to your liking. Then the next developer will come along and complain about your code and probably change it back to be more like what your friend did.

Comment: Every **Good** programmer thinks their old code sucks, let alone the code from others.

Comment: @Brad - I agree, I thought of putting that in there but then it seemed to wordy for such a succinct point.

Comment: +1 for other's code sucks. Specially if you have to maintain it.

Comment: I think the OP is asking how bring the subject of code quality up with a colleague without offending him/her. An answer like this isn't very useful because it is basically saying don't say anything at all. I would much rather have someone approach me with some constructive criticism than stay silent, because there are a lot of things I don't know that I don't know, and I would appreciate someone taking the time to help me learn. Also, I'd rather try and teach someone how to make their code more readable once than deal with their mess for the next few years.

Comment: @Rachel-Most people have worked with the guy who complains all the time and eventually nobody respects that person's views, even if valid. Most people have also thought they were being helpful by giving unsolicited advice only to be met with less than positive responses. Since providing critique of the original programmers code is not the posters job description (since he isn't the guy's mentor, lead or doing a code review) the odds are that nothing good will come from his saying anything. The righteous view is to say you want constructive criticism but when it comes on you; do you really?

Comment: @Dunk My personal option is yes! I'm almost completely self-taught and I love it when people take the time to show me things I didn't know before. For example, my early projects are things like single-class files with horrible naming conventions and no version control. I didn't know any better. There's no harm in bringing up the subject in a non-threatening way while taking to someone and seeing how they react to it, as long as you're willing to drop the subject if the person is unwilling to change their ways.

Comment: @Dunk and I disagree that "likely nothing good will come from his saying anything". If approached right, and if the person is willing to learn (I feel its almost impossible to be a good programmer without being willing to learn), the person will start coding better and it will make future upkeep of his/her projects a lot easier. If you say nothing, you're probably stuck with maintaining projects using his/her (lack of) coding standards in the future.

Answer (score 3):

Get some background about what was going on within the company and the team when this project was written. Ask this dev for some feedback on how he thought the project went. Has his style changed? If given the opportunity, what would he do differently?

He may agree with your standards, but just didn't have the luxury of applying them during the creation of this app or just didn't know about them.

Either your group has no standards or code review policy or a serious problem with enforcement. You may be holding an opinion of one.

Comment: I like this answer.  For example, if your coworker was in a frantic rush at midnight to fix bug#1235 for a patch, such crappy code would be acceptable.  But it should still have a comment like "TODO hasty patch for release 1.2.4, fixme".

Answer (score 3):

I'll admit it, I am sometimes that guy. When I am, I will have my reasons, usually time constraint, death-march projects, instructions such as "now, not perfect" etc. Very rarely, it's because of a bad day. I am happy to get asked about any issues, it gives me a chance to become a better developer. Provided a) You are reasonable about what will be changed (ain't that badly broke, agree to don't fix), and b) your not a nut job dictator  who believes your way is the only way.

To approach me about it, do not ask "Why". Why is a fighting word, a challenge, and is ultimately destructive. If you find yourself using Why too much, change it to I. 
"Why did you call this x" becomes, "I would have used index, it's more descriptive than x."

The best way is to state what you would have done, or would have preferred. Explain that what you are seeing does not met certain standards, and that you would like to see it improved. My guess is that 99% of the time,  the response will be "so would I, but........"

Comment: +1 for the "Why" warning: most people go on the defensive as soon as you say "Why"

Comment: Me too, I'm sometimes the guy producing poor quality code not because I don't care but because of constraints like this one time I was the only developer doing 3 developers' work. I did went back to improve the quality when project finally had budget to add new developers though.

Answer (score 1):

It is unlikely that the author of the code will come back to fix his code for you out of pure good will, or that your employer will pay him to do that. So, either way, you are scr*wed.

If you believe that the mess the code is in will have a severe detrimental effect on your performance while working on it, be sure to save a backup of the original code somewhere so that you can prove that it was a mess when it was delivered to you. So, if your employer confronts you later about your poor performance, you can cover your ass.

Still, it may look to your employer like an excuse, so try to avoid even that happening if you can.

Comment: No need for a backup. That's what source control is for! If there is no source control being used, you've got bigger problems than just dealing with messy code.

Comment: Also, once messy code has been put into production, any attempt to "clean up" or refactor it should require a full regression test. And that can be very expensive and time consuming. After all: "if it ain't broke (according to *real* defects filed by users and tracked in a trouble-ticket system), don't fix it!"

Answer (score 1):

Think about what good mentioning him that he has a bad coding style would do you or him?

Perhaps it's better to try to improve your company's QA procedures.

Comment: QA in my experience doesn't involve code review.  :(

Comment: @Karl - QA is supposed to be involved in the entire process, assuring quality is met in all work products. Otherwise, what is the point of QA?

Comment: @dunk It's supposed to but I don't know many places where it actually does.

Answer (score 1):

You need to find out two things: What is your goal? How would you like to be approached yourself?

If your colleague, with 20+ years of programming behind him, is really, really open-minded, you can just go talk to him and point out specific examples, tell him why they looked wrong to you and discuss alternatives. Because he's really, really open-minded and keen to learn, he'll listen, a discussion will ensue, and he'll understand your points and you'll both live happily ever after.

In my experience, though, the colleague is most likely programming like that because he just doesn't care about style. It could be because he's really in the wrong job, or it could be because, in 20+ years of programming, he never found a reason to worry about it - maybe his code just works and he moves on.

If the latter is the case, you're just going to waste your and his time, and you may make a dent in your relationship if it turns into an argument. So what is your goal here?

Do you want him to clean up his code so that you can work on nicer code? 
Do you want him to learn and improve? 
Do you want to feel good about being a better coder?
Do you want your boss to know that you're a better coder than him?

The first one is not going to happen and the third is already established, although you probably want him to recognize it as well - good friend, father figure?

If you really want him to learn and improve, then figure out how you would like to be approached in the reverse situation, and do the same. And figure out what would annoy you, and make sure you don't do that.

The forth one is easy: either you want a better salary, and then you just demand it during the next feedback meeting (it doesn't really matter how good you are in this industry) or you want more responsibility and then you just keep doing a good job until you get it.

Comment: I like your thought process here. Though you missed a step in your fourth paragraph, which is that I don't want bugs in the app. I don't care about my boss knowing, otherwise I'd approach her. There's a bit of 1 and 2 in my thinking, but mainly I know this will be very hard for multiple people to maintain going forward, and codebases change hands alot, so a good style makes everybody's job easier.

Answer (score 0):

Suggest you boss that you have been seeing some crazy code and ask him to put all possible staff on some programming courses. I think he should be aware that his apps are being filled with crappy code.

Comment: Please explain how behavior like mixed naming, sections commented out and no documentation can be corrected by a programming course.

Comment: Its a subtle way of saying "here some people is making crap" and avoiding confrontation. And a good teacher can make a big difference on how people code because they are forced to see how someone, who knows what is doing, does stuff (and explains). If they dont know, someone should teach them and explain why and how do stuff, and i think is better for the office atmosphere that a teacher does that instead of a coworker. (Unless you are a well respected coworker who people go for answers, if not, people mostly doesnt want answers from the ones they see at a similar level)

Comment: Also, most people doesnt read books that companies give them, thats why i think a mandatory course is better.

Comment: If you work at a company where people don't read books voluntarily and don't learn new tricks from each other, then you deserve the crappy code you'll get as a result ;-)

Comment: I agree with that nikie :-)